# Quickest way to concatenate all String elements from List to String

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, concatenation

I have a large amount of User objects on my website, each containing a List of forums that they administrate. I have created a page that will display a paginated list of all users that administrate a forum as well as all of the forum names.

So for example

### Travis - FTB, SCR, SWM, BSB

### Tom - FTB, SCR, SWM, BSB, TRK, BSK

However some users may administrate over 300 different topics and is causing the pages a really long time to process.

I have tried the following ways to get it process faster, but all of them are taking about the same amount of time (too long).

```
//Join
topicString = String.Join(", ", user.Topics)
(note that Topics.ToString returns a 3 character ID)

//StringBuilder
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(3*user.Topics.Count() + 2*user.Topics.Count());
foreach(var topic in user.Topics) {
   stringBuilder.Append(topic.Code);
   stringBuilder.Append(", ");
}
codes = stringBuilder.ToString();
codes = codes.Remove(codes.Length-2);


//Classic concatenation
foreach(var topic in user.Topics) {
    codes += topic.Code;
    codes += ", ";
}
codes = codes.Remove(codes.Length-2);
```

Each page contains 15 users

When all 15 users contain around 3 topics each it takes about 1 second to load the page. Any page that has 1 user containing over 100 topics, the page load skyrockets to near 20 seconds.

Could there be a way with threading to speed things up?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the join? Seems to be a bit too much 20 seconds for a join of 100 strings of 3 characters

Comment: I agree with Steve - you are talking about "page load", not "string concatenation time". This is probably not the bottleneck. The bottleneck is probably due to subsequently running 100 more queries on the database than you need (or something along those lines).

Comment: I suggest you use `var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); sw.Start();` before and `sw.Stop(); var time = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;` after the suspected bottleneck. My guess is that the string concatenation won't even register 1 second.

Comment: Stopwatch reads 18 seconds. So maybe it is from lazy loading the database?

Comment: You need to show full code of the method which you use to generate response. Problem is obviously not related to String concatenation.

Comment: @NightOwl888 the problem was lazy loading from the dB. As soon as I used Include to the path, it is faster than ever! Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that the is string operation is a culprit maybe a bit premature. If I were you, I'd run the whole page under a profiler such as JProfiler and see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments mentioned the performance issue caused by fetching data from database not to string concatenation. And lazy loading was confusing here.

String builder will show its power when the string length is more than 1 million characters. When you use the `String.Join()` method it will use string builder internally.

A bit performance improvement to your code is to set the string builder length before converting it to string to avoid creating of a large string object twice:

```
// StringBuilder
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var topic in user.Topics) {
   stringBuilder.Append(topic.Code);
   stringBuilder.Append(", ");
}
stringBuilder.length--;
codes = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

It is not necessary to specify string builder size because its resizing algorithm is fast enough.

I worked with the string builder class with size more than 100 million characters and in that situation, it is approximately 10,000 times faster than normal string concatenation.